# Oracle SQL - Create identifier for couple of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with the following problem, I have the follwing data in a table:

| Param ID | Param Val | Other Cols |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | XXX |
| 1 | 15 | XXX |
| 1 | 16 | XXX |
| 1 | 16 | XXX |
| 2 | 21 | XXX |
| 2 | 21 | XXX |
| 2 | 22 | XXX |
| 2 | 22 | XXX |

I would like to select a new colum in order to create 4 sets of data to have all the possible combination between the values of parameter 1 and 2; so I would like to obtain something like this:

| Set | Param ID | Param Val | Other Cols |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15 | XXX |
| 2 | 1 | 15 | XXX |
| 3 | 1 | 16 | XXX |
| 4 | 1 | 16 | XXX |
| 1 | 2 | 21 | XXX |
| 3 | 2 | 21 | XXX |
| 2 | 2 | 22 | XXX |
| 4 | 2 | 22 | XXX |

So for example for the Set 1 I will have the Couple of values 15 and 21, for the set 2 the values 15 and 22 etc etc.

I tried using different analytic functions, but I was not able to have what I need.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 15 "VAL" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 15 "VAL" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 16 "VAL" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 16 "VAL" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 21 "VAL" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 21 "VAL" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 22 "VAL" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 22 "VAL" From Dual 
        )
```

**UPDATED AFTER THE COMMENT**
If you want the combinations then you will have to use the MODEL clause. To do that you should prepare the data (cte named grid) a bit so you could do the addressing to the particular data and manage all the combinations you want. It looks like here:

```sql
    grid AS
        ( Select  Distinct
                  Sum(1) OVER(Partition By ID Order By ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "IDS_TOTAL_ORDER",
                  Sum(1) OVER(Partition By VAL Order By VAL ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "VALS_TOTAL_ORDER",
                  ID "ID",  
                  VAL "VAL"
            From
                  tbl   
            Order By ID 
        )
Select     SET_ID, ID, VAL
From (   Select   0 "SET_ID", IDS_TOTAL_ORDER, VALS_TOTAL_ORDER, ID "ID", VAL "VAL"
         From     grid  
     )
    MODEL
        Dimension By (ID, IDS_TOTAL_ORDER, VALS_TOTAL_ORDER)
        Measures(SET_ID, VAL)
        RULES
            (
                SET_ID[1, ANY, ANY] = CV(IDS_TOTAL_ORDER),
                SET_ID[2, 1, 1] = CV(IDS_TOTAL_ORDER),
                SET_ID[2, 2, 2] = CV(IDS_TOTAL_ORDER) + 1,
                SET_ID[2, 3, 1] = CV(IDS_TOTAL_ORDER) - 1,
                SET_ID[2, 4, 2] = CV(IDS_TOTAL_ORDER)
            )
Order By  ID, IDS_TOTAL_ORDER
```

This way you can get any combination. Here is your result:

| SET_ID | ID | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 16 |
| 4 | 1 | 16 |
| 1 | 2 | 21 |
| 3 | 2 | 21 |
| 2 | 2 | 22 |
| 4 | 2 | 22 |

More about MODEL clause: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm

Sets now looks like here:

| SET_ID | IDS_VALS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/15, 2/21 |
| 2 | 1/15, 2/22 |
| 3 | 1/16, 2/21 |
| 4 | 1/16, 2/22 |

Regards...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, as per the other answer (now disappeared) the result is different than the desired one. In your result the sets 1 and 2 are exactly the same (also the 3 and 4), while I'm trying to obtain 4 different sets with all the possible combination of values. Set 1 should be 15/21, set 2: 15/22, set 3: 16/21 set 4: 16/22.

Comment: @The_Rkp Just posted the Addition to the answer (regarding the comment). Regards...

Comment: The solution proposed seems very specific when you need 4 sets of values. What happen if my table contains more rows and I need for example 6 or 8 sets? Anyway I didn't know this MODEL clause, I will study it further, thanks

Comment: Yes, the MODEL clause is quite specific, but it lets you freedom to address the data with an addressing system quite similar to excel worksheet. Plus you can use multiple addressings with ANY, and/or CV() operators. There is the option of using iterations and much more other kinky stuff. I can't say what suites you the best with your data. The basic is to prepare the dataset for modeling in a way that all you need is addressable.

Answer (score 0):

Despite a good hint on the MODEL clause, I guess I will go for a solution combining cross join and unpivot, maybe it is not the best, but it fit my needs.

```
WITH tbl AS
(
       Select 1 "ID", 15 "VAL" From Dual Union All
       Select 1 "ID", 16 "VAL" From Dual Union All
       Select 2 "ID", 21 "VAL" From Dual Union All
       Select 2 "ID", 22 "VAL" From Dual )
SELECT *
FROM   (
              SELECT ROWNUM AS SET_ID,
                     id1,
                     id4
              FROM   (
                            SELECT
                                   CASE a.id
                                          WHEN 1 THEN a.val
                                          ELSE 0
                                   END AS id1,
                                   CASE a.id
                                          WHEN 2 THEN a.val
                                          ELSE 0
                                   END AS id2,
                                   CASE b.id
                                          WHEN 1 THEN b.val
                                          ELSE 0
                                   END AS id3,
                                   CASE b.id
                                          WHEN 2 THEN b.val
                                          ELSE 0
                                   END AS id4
                            FROM   tbl a,
                                   tbl b)
              WHERE  id2 = 0
              AND    id3 = 0) UNPIVOT (VAL FOR ID IN (id1 AS '1',
                                                      id4 AS '2'))
```

that results in :

| SET_ID | ID | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 21 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 1 | 16 |
| 3 | 2 | 21 |
| 4 | 1 | 16 |
| 4 | 2 | 22 |

tried with all the combination of source data, and it seems work :)